# Docker takes a very long time to start MacOS

Tags: macos, docker

Sometimes on my Mac the Docker takes a very long time to start. I tried to reboot the machine than restart docker one more time and for the first couple times it helped, now even reboot can't help to start docker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the cure, just press `enter` after this command
`screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty`

Comment: [screen is terminating] this is what the output of the terminal for this command. Also, It didn't fix issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change memory allocation for docker desktop

> > Click on >> *Docker desktop icon >> Preferences*  [ Add CPU 2 and memory 2.0 GB]