# docker desktop Preferences settings page is not loading and state is docker desktop is starting from forever

Tags: macos, docker, kubernetes

Main issue is docker desktop is not starting in mac &
The status bar is showing docker desktop is starting but this process is not ending

I tried system reboot multiple times, Reinstallation of different docker desktop versions but didn't help.

I found answers which mentioned to change the Preferences -> Settings and allocation of different memory and core to docker desktop [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65340358/5410940) but settings page is also in endless loading state

[image: DOCKER settings not loading state]

Internet speed ~10MBps| mac OS 10.14 Mojave | 16GB RAM|. Please help fixing it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When Docker preference setting page is not working

> > Click on Docker desktop icon >> Preferences ( This page is not loading) >> Click on the Troubleshoot icon ( top right corner with a bug image placeholder)  >> Reset to factory defaults

Comment: Too radical though?

Comment: @mrateb I didn't get this correctly. I would be more than happy to edit with your help to make it more helpful

Comment: Maybe radical, but after trying soo many things, this works perfect. THanks!

Comment: This is also not working.

Comment: I did "reset to factory default". But no changes. docker setting screen is loading now... forever..

Answer (score 6):

I've been trying so many things to make it work and the only thing that worked for me in Windows was running this in cmd

`"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchDaemon`

I took this on [Docker cannot start on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459280/docker-cannot-start-on-windows)

Answer (score 2):

Try this: [Github Link](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4239) it works for me!

I found a magical solution, first open the docker preferences settings, and then click the docker icon in the status bar to select restart. At this time, you will be surprised to find that the settings UI is no longer in the loading state, then select Kubernetes in this short time, cancel the enable Kubernetes option, finally click the application below and restart. docker returned to normal. All this should be caused by Kubernetes not starting normally.

Docker version 2.2.0.5
macOS High Sieera 10.13.6

Answer (score 2):

On my side I had a similar issue on my Windows machine.

It was probably caused by a forced shutdown after sleep mode (perhaps no more battery).

I tried many things like restarting the Services but it was not working when I started to watch the folder `.docker` in my home directory.

I did this:

- I first stopped my Docker Desktop process
- then I deleted the file named `.token_seed.lock` in `${USER_HOME}/.docker/`
- Start the Docker Desktop from the shortcut

and after that my Docker was running without any issue and my stored images were correctly displayed (and starting / stopping properly).

Answer (score 1):

Docker demon isn’t responding all your need is

1. Quit docker desktop.
2. force quit all docker processes in activity monitor (this should force stop the demon).
3. start docker desktop again.

Comment: this solution is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and what it solved it was to force Docker using Linux language. You can use this command for that:

```
'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCLI.exe' -SwitchLinuxEngine
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - If you haven't already, follow Microsoft's Steps 4-6

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package

After setting up your distro

2 - Inside Docker Click on the Bug Icon (next to the settings top)

3 - Do Factory reset for Docker

4 - Stop Docker from Task Manager

5 - Run this command

```
'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCLI.exe' -SwitchLinuxEngine
```

6 - Now Launch Docker and it will work! hopefully.

If it doesn't (in step 3 I also deleted Containers, WSL settings, Hyper V) from Docker Settings (Be careful deleting your own Containers is dangerous)

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the exact same problem right after I added a key-value pair into the [Docker daemon configuration file](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#configure-the-docker-daemon) through the `Docker Desktop -> Preferences -> Docker Engine tab`. The change broke my Docker engine and I couldn't undo my changes through UI since the UI was broken and showing the loading animation.

I solved the problem by manually removing the changes I made. The daemon configuration file is located in `~/.docker/daemon.json`.

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved this problem. 
I'm using docker on Ubuntu vmware.
I think, the cause is just docker engine is not started.
The solution is below:
[image]

This function is for virtual machine in the virtual machine.
Oh yes, so now we can run the docker engine successfully.
Of course, the "forever loading" problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case in Windows 10 I opened Docker Desktop settings and then clicked the docker icon in the status bar to select restart. After restart already opened Settings was loaded successfully